# Changing Platform Toolset

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to change Platform Toolset in VS C++ 2015 to some older stuff because my friends lack v140. When I go to configuration of project I can only choose v140. How can I install v120 ones for example. I cannot find any downloads for that.

Comment: You need an MSDN subscription to download older versions of VS.

Comment: I have MSDN subscription from my school. So I have to download older versions yes?